# entity framework in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an error on my codes and error is on

```
public MyEntity() : base("name=MyEntity")
```

And error is:

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

and these are my code:

```
public partial class MyEntity : DbContext
{
    public MyEntity() : base("name=MyEntity"){}   

    public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FileResume> FileResumes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sample>()
            .Property(e => e.Date)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related. Why do you need to ad sysdiagram as DbSet? It's a system table.

Comment: Add the code of the inner exception too